# Pyqt5 QLCDNumber is not showing seconds (third object)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlcdnumber

I have a QLCDNumber I need to show 3 parts (hrs:minutes:seconds). So, I set it as `lcdnumber.display("00:00:00")`, it show only two parts (00:00). I think the problem is with ":". I tried to separate and use text manipulation, it didn't work, only shows the first two parts. How can I show the third part of seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the number of digits you want to display using the [`digitCount`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html#digitCount-prop) property, in this case it must be 8 (6 for the zeros and 2 for ":"):

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    w = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber()
    w.setDigitCount(8)
    w.display("00:00:00")
    w.resize(640, 120)
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

[image]